# Laravel - Get records from one table that doesn't exist in another with a where clause attached

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I've got the following SQL tables (in MySQL):

```
students
+-----+------------+
| id  | first_name | 
+-----+------------+
| 01  | John       |
+-----+------------+
| 02  | Jane       | 
+-----+------------+
| 03  | Peter      | 
+-----+------------+

academics
+-----+-----------+----------+------+
| id  | year_start| year_end |status|
+-----+-----------+----------+------+
| 10  | 2016      | 2017     |1     |
+-----+-----------+----------+------+
| 20  | 2017      | 2018     |0     |
+-----+-----------+----------+------+

enrollments
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | student_id | academic_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 01         | 10          |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 2  | 02         | 20          |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 3  | 01         | 20          |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

How do I get students from both the `students table` and the `enrollments table` who are not enrolled for the current academic year or of whom no records exists in the `enrollments table` for the current academic year.

For now I can get the student form the `students table` who has no enrollment details in the `enrollments table` with this query:

```
$students = \DB::table('students')
        ->select(
            'students.id',
            'first_name'
        )
        ->leftJoin('enrollments','enrollments.student_id','=','students.id')
        ->whereNull('enrollments.student_id')
        ->get();
```

Based on the data in the table above this query will return student `Peter - 03`.

*BUT HOW CAN I GET STUDENTS WHO HAVE NO ENROLLMENT DETAILS FOR THE CURRENT ACADEMIC YEAR?*

This is how I determine the current academic year:

```
$current_academic = Academic::where('status', 1)->first();
```

With the existing query how do I join on the `academics table` so that I can query out students who have no enrollment records for the current academic year. 
Will appreciate your earnest answers and suggestions.

Comment: And what do you get with that $current_academic?

Comment: I get the current academic year. In this case **2017/2018** whose id is **10**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$current_academic = Academic::where('status', 1)->first();

$students = \DB::table('students')
    ->select(
        'students.id',
        'first_name'
    )
    ->whereNotExists( function ($query) use ($current_academic) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('enrollments')
        ->whereRaw('students.id = enrollments.student_id')
        ->where('enrollments.academic_id', '=', $current_academic->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Let's give some details:

1- `whereNotExists` clause will return only students that doesn't have any row in the sub query.

2- the sub query select students that exists in enrollments table and their academics_id is 10

Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by "their id is 10"? No student id is 10 in the enrollments table.

Comment: I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'` I think it is because of this: `use ($current_academic) ` that you added. Can you help with a fix?

Comment: Don't bother I fix it already. Will update your code later after testing to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I just forget to replace '<>' by '=', please see the updated query

Comment: Thanks man got it working. You know today marks the 3rd day I have spend on this query. Yesterday I closer but didn't know how to pass parameters to the whereNotExists function because I didn't see examples of such in the docs. Bless God you came by today.

Comment: can I talk to you about something important via social media or email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161206/discussion-between-younel-and-nathan-siafa).

Comment: @YouneL please take a look at this link is have the same problem, but this not worked for me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182670/how-to-get-record-from-one-table-that-dose-not-match-in-another-table-in-laravel

Comment: @ZiaYamin The link is down 404

Comment: @YouneL sorry bro, take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347909/how-to-get-all-records-from-one-table-that-not-exist-in-another-table-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

```
$students = \DB::table('students')
        ->select(
            'students.id',
            'first_name'
        )
        ->leftJoin('enrollments','enrollments.student_id','=','students.id')
        ->whereNull('enrollments.student_id')
        ->orWhere('enrollments.academic_id','<>',$current_academic->id)
        ->get();
```

Comment: This will return students: John and peter. Take a look in the enrollments table student John is enroll in the current academic year.

Comment: Man... that's the reason of the "<>". You will get Peter because of the null, and Jane because she is not enrolled with academics 10.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting John instead of Jane. It's true that Jane is not enrolled with academic 10, so I should get Peter and Jane but that is not the case.

Comment: That's all I can do without the actual database... I don't know, I think the query gets what you asked.

Comment: I think the reason why I'm receiving Peter, Jane and John is that John has two enrollments - past(2017/2018 id-20) and current(2016/2017 id-10). With that his id is repeated twice in the enrollments table. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this the most eloquential way possible:

First off, you need to have this in your Student.php model file

```
public function academics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Academic', 'enrollments', 'student_id', 'academic_id'); 
}
```

and this in your Academic.php model file

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student', 'enrollments', 'academic_id','student_id'); 
}
```

now you can get what you want this way:

```
$students = \App\Student::whereDoesntHave('academics')
->orWhereHas('academics',function($q) use ($academic){
  $q->where('id',$academic->id)->count();
},'=',0)->get();
```

Comment: Wow. Who doesn't love clarity. Taking a look now.

Comment: Is this not needed? `->get()`

Comment: Certainly.Corrected. Did it work for you? Quite elegant!

Comment: I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`

Comment: Added the semi-colon after the equal sign on the where statement and now I'm getting `Can't use method return value in write context`

Comment: I'm getting `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `academics` inner join `enrollments` on `academics`.`id` = `enrollments`.`academic_id` where `students`.`id` = `enrollments`.`student_id` and `academics`.`id` = 1)`

Comment: This looks amazing! Thanks for sharing!